# What does non-degeneracy of of the diffusion coefficient in the context of a SDE mean?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

In the introduction of  a paper I was reading the author writes without elaborating that

**"
In the case of a non-degenerate diffusion coefficient, Stroock and Varadhan , proved the existence of a unique weak solution for a SDE with bounded measurable drift , and bounded continuous diffusion coefficients.
"**

So if the SDE is 
$$
dX_t=\mu(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t
$$

So what does non-degeneracy of the diffusion coefficient mean here? Does it mean that $\sigma(X_t)\sigma(X_t)^T$ is invertible for all $t\ge 0$ almost surely? 
Or does it say something directly about the function $\sigma$?

Comment: What is for sure is that the Stroock and Varadhan theory needs for the matrix $b=\sigma.\sigma^T$ to be well behaved because you have to be able to find a square root of $b$ (that is $\sigma$) so the fact that $b$ is positive definite is necessary (for a symmetric matrix it is sufficient for it to be invertible) but I can't remember if their theory also needs conditions on the smoothness of $b$. I think it is true, but I am not sure wether it is related to the fact that the diffusion coefficient is said to be non-degenerate. regards